# Tesseract on Linux crashes Glassfish

Tags: java, linux, tesseract, tess4j

We are using Tess4J/Tesseract to perform OCR on a webapp. On Windows everyting works fine but when deployed on a Linux machine the program crashes, kills the glassfish process and outputs a dump file: `hs_err_pidXXXXX.log`.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9fdd5322a0, pid=10412, tid=140324597778176
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract.so+0x2532a0]  ERRCODE::error(char const*, TessErrorLogCode, char const*, ...) const+0x190
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fa00c42d800):  JavaThread "pool-26-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=10705, stack(0x00007f9fddbdc000,0x00007f9fddcdd000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000
```

The tesseract commands works and correctly converts images to text.
We have tried the [LC_NUMERIC](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/8393fd13/) solution but still doesn't work.

Our Tesseract java code is something like this

```
File file; // ...
boolean hOcr; // ...
Rectangle rec; // ...
OcrResult result;
//Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1();
try {
    instance.setHocr(hOcr);            
    ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
    String res;
    if (rec == null) {
        res = instance.doOCR(file);
    } else {
        res = instance.doOCR(file, rec);
    }
    result = new OcrResult(res, 0, true);
} catch (TesseractException e) {
    log.error("error tesseract", e);
    // process error
} catch (Error e) {
    log.error("error tesseract", e);
    // process error
}
```

Our specs

- Tesseract 3.02.02
- Tess4J
- CentoOS 6.4
- Java 1.7
- Glassfish 4.1

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does ImageIO know about the instance of Tesseract1?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, so I'm guessing not

Comment: Since you use Java 64-bit, is that Tesseract 64-bit as well? And make sure `setDatpath` to the parent of `tessdata` directory.

Comment: Thanks for comment. It turned out to be a series of factors: setting datapath to TESSDATA_PREFIX and applying patches ([found here](https://github.com/knime-ip/knip-tess4j), credits to the author) due to a known [issue concerning locale](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=910)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a combination of factors:

- setting datapath to TESSDATA_PREFIX on server JVM settings in Glassfish
- and most importantly, applying patches on Tesseract ([found here](https://github.com/knime-ip/knip-tess4j), credits to the author) due to a known [issue concerning system locale](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=910) - somehow the bug fixes were not applied in latest versions